# Loop example from Eloquent javascript is not running

Tags: javascript

I'm reading eloquent javascript and Im at the part where they tell you how to loop. Tried googling the answer but nothing pertaining to this popped up. when I run the code on the browser it stalls and I have to close the window. Any info on why I am having this problem would be greatly appreciated

```
<script>
 var result = 1;
 var counter = 0;
 while (counter < 10) {
 result = result *2;
 counter = + 1;
}
alert(result);
</script>
```

Comment: counter+=1 is the right syntax

Comment: This particular loop could be written much more cleanly as an upwards `for` loop or downwards `while` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
counter = + 1;
```

is bad, it should probably be:

```
counter += 1;
// or
counter = counter + 1;
```

If `counter` never gets incremented the while loop will run forever.

Comment: Is this book a good place to start for javascrip? While gooling I have come across problems that people are having with the examples in the book. a lot of books I have read seem to have glitches like this in them and being a beginner, things like this can drive you crazy because you are following a book that you assume to be right. It makes me feel as if i'm the cause. Nay good javascript recommendations ?

Comment: I mostly just learned by doing. Code examples in books are notorious for containing little mistakes. If you've read programming books before mistakes like this shouldn't stump you. Whenever a program locks up there is an infinite loop, any `for` or `while` loop is immediately suspect, trace it, fix it.

Comment: I'm to obsessed with programming to be stumped. and I run across these things all the time.Just was wondering if there was a book that is "THEE" book for js. Thanks